# Unable to view continuous images in webview

Tags: javascript, android-studio

The problem that I'm facing is that I have a function that is continuously receiving byte array of images i.e receiving multiple images at a high rate.I want to display these images in the webview. So that I could see the changing images at a speed and it would appear to me as if I am watching a video.

what I have done is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and then passed this string as a parameter to html file

```
document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," +      YourByte;
```

But when I view the webview only 1 or 2 images appear rather than 100's of them.
WHAT is the reason and how could it be resolved?

Comment: Show us the full code. Also, do you think this is the right approach? Not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: What i hv done is that i hv converted bytes array into a bitmap  Bitmap mybitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w*3, h*3, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

                canvas = new Canvas(mybitmap); I apply a standard procedure convert bytes array to bitmap and draw it on the canvas using canvas.drawBitmap(pixelsPreview, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h, true, bitmapPaint);and then the above code.Any other if not this u could suggest

Comment: My aim is that i hv a byte array  continuosly updating and i want to display it on the webview.On webview i want to see images and as the array is continuosly updatng i want to  see different images on the web

Comment: I don't see any canvas in your original post. Please do post all the necessary code bits.